# ISA Server and Exchange - Port 25 Issues

Tags: exchange-2003, spam, isa-server

What is a best practice method for minimising spam issues when spammers are getting through our ISA 2004 gateway and spamming from our exchange server?

Is there a fantastic document that someone knows about for setting up exchange server 2003.

Comment: They're spamming your internal users?  Or they're sending spam outbound from your Exchange server?

Comment: Agreed. Where are spammers coming from, and who are they sending spam to?

Comment: They are sending spam outbound from our Exchange server. It's causing our domain to get put on blacklists.

Comment: Do you have relaying disabled?

Comment: Ok, but where do they connect from? The Internet? Or do you have spammers on your internal network (maybe infected computers)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to restrict relaying through your server - In ESM, expand *Administrative Groups > Admin Group Name > Servers > Servername > Protocols > SMTP*.  Right-click on "Default SMTP Virtual Server" and go to properties.  Click the "Access" tab and click the "Relay..." button.  It should hopefully be set to "Only the list below" and only have known IP addresses or subnets that YOU have control of.  If it is set to "All except the list below" and there are no entries in the list, you have an open relay.  If there are entries for networks that YOU do not control, you should probably look into removing them from this list.  No fantastic document, but that is basically it.  Well here is a good article at least - http://www.petri.co.il/preventing_exchange_2000_2003_from_relaying.htm